# jQuery ajax makes click event triggered multiple times by VM

Tags: jquery

Here's my `base.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container = $('.notificationBox');
    var icon = $('#notificationIcon');
    var badge = $('.badge');
    var notif = $('.notif-row');

    container.load('notification');
    container.removeClass('hidden');

    icon.click(function()
    {
         console.log('clicked');
    });
});
```

Here's the screenshot of the console message:
[image]

I have no idea what went wrong, I have been debugging for hours. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you

Comment: That click function must be getting hooked up multiple times somehow

Comment: put a breakpoint on `icon.click` line and see how many times is executed. Definitively my feeling is that base.js is referenced many times on your page